# пытаюсь научиться парсингу, не понимаю, что сделать с кодировкой русских символов, подскажите как сделать так, чтобы выводило русские буквы

Tags: python, html, beautiful-soup, lxml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

снизу вывод, пытался сделать с помощью encode, но не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно выяснить, что за кодировка у файла index2, если ты из под Windows, то попробуй вот такой код

```
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

   with open('blank/index2.html', 'r', encoding='cp1251') as f:
       src = f.read()
   soup = BS(src, 'lxml')
   title = soup.find('title')
   print(title)
```

Comment: Исправьте, пожалуйста, отступ в src = f.read()

Comment: @СергейКох, поправил, спасибо